# TCP sliding window problem about largest sequence number

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols

If a sender sends a packet with sequence number 1000 and its window size has been constant at 20, what is the largest sequence number that the receiver has definitely received?()

The answer is 980.

How can I solve this problem? I think the the largest sequence number is 1000.

I'm going to cry.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The sliding send window is the data "in flight" - it's been sent but not acknowledged yet. If the sender receives acknowledgement for the lowest sequence in the windows, the window advances and the next segment is sent.

Therefore, when the sequence 1000 has just been sent, the window contains sequences 981-1000. 980 is the highest sequence that has slid out of the window after acknowledgment.